# How to make third party magento extension compatible with store theme

Tags: extensions, ce-1.9.0.1, rwd-theme

What is best way to make third party extension compatible with store theme which is not default theme.

**For example I'm Using**

THEME: rwd

EXTENSION: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/layered-navigation-seo.html

 **extension works good in default theme but in rwd theme it is not compatible.**

What should I update and where should I update it.

I ask this question in general, answer for the above example would be appreciated.

*This type of issue become common with rwd theme, most of the old extensions works good with default theme but not with rwd theme. Many useful extension have such issues and most  of their authors are not active. That's why I asked this question here.*

Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15263779

Thank you.

Comment: You should ask the extension provider for compatibility.

Comment: @ mbalparda, most of old extension's authors are not active.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with many of these modules is that they place the template, layout, and skin assets inside of the default/default theme, rather than the base/default them. The default/default theme is deprecated and is no longer a part of the fallback chain.

For example, that Layered Navigation SEO module that you linked to adds its custom files in these directories:

```
app/design/frontend/default/default/layout/catalin_seo.xml
app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalin_seo/*
skin/frontend/default/default/css/price_slider/style.css
skin/frontend/default/default/images/price_slider/*
skin/frontend/default/default/js/catalin_seo
```

To fix this problem, you need to move those files into a theme that IS included as a part of the fallback chain. So that would be either base/default, rwd/default, or your custom package/theme. Since the files are not all namespaced into vendor/module directories, I would be hesitant to move them into base/default, but I think that is probably your best option so that they work with all themes that you might deploy in the future. So in short, move all of the above files into their equivalent directory locations in `app/design/frontend/base/default/` and `skin/frontend/base/default`.

Comment: Thanks Erik Hansen, Already I followed similar steps, they did not solve my issues.

Comment: Too bad. If those steps don't solve your issue, then you will need to dig into the code more deeply to figure out what is happening.